# How to set partial default input with scanf in C?

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to programming and I am writing a program to convert decimal into binary for a numerical analysis course. I am a bit stuck on how to handle variable forms of input. For example, the input can be in one of the two following forms:

`Input: 15` or `Input: 15 / 2`

If it were only one of the two cases, I know how to handle the input in either:

`scanf("%d", &userInput);` and `scanf("%d / %d", &numerIn, &denomIn);`  , respectively.

I've tried a number of tactics with no luck. I came close with the following:

```
    (1)    int numerIn, denomIn = 1;        
    (2)    printf("Enter decimal number: ");
    (3)    scanf("%d", &numerIn);
    (4)    if (!feof(stdin)) {
    (5)       scanf(" / %d", &denomIn);
    (6)    }
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work smoothly. I've tried messing around with different combinations of spaces before and after the %d's and / in lines 3 and 5 to no avail. I've also thought that maybe there is some way to write the program such that if nothing is entered after the first integer that the program can know to automatically default to using the default 1 value in denomIn, but I can't figure this out yet either.

Is there a way to go about this requirement that I am overlooking? I am terribly new to C programming, so it is very likely I'm making an embarrassingly novice mistake here. That being said, are there any good articles that explain precisely how the input buffer works? This is a bit confusing to me.

Thanks in advance! Any insight would be much appreciated at this point.

Comment: I'd skip trying to get scanf to do the work. As you're finding out, it's never going to be correct. Instead, try reading in the whole input then using strtok or a custom parser to work through the input.

Comment: If this is an assignment that _must_ use `scanf()`, the key is to check the result of `scanf("%d",...)` and if successful, `scanf(" /%d",...)` checking its result too.   Better to use `fgets()` and process the string.

Comment: Do not use `feof()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the entire line using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).
2. Use [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to parse the line.

The links to `fgets` and `strtok` provide example code that you can use as your starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `scanf` is not something that I would use in a production program. It's much too fragile. But for simple test programs it can be more convenient than writing your own parser.

The advantage of using `scanf` is that it handles white space variations, and does numeric conversions, while taking care of minor parsing tasks like looking for the `'/'` character

The disadvantage of using `scanf` is that if something is wrong with the input there's a good chance that `scanf` won't detect it, and an equally good chance that `scanf` will leave `stdin` in an unknown state (which requires additional code to clean up the mess).

One way to work around `scanf's` abysmal error handling is to use `fgets` read a line of user input, and then use `sscanf` to parse the line. That way, if something goes wrong, at least `stdin` is left in a known state.

---

The following code demonstrates how to use `fgets` and `sscanf` to get user input. First `fgets` reads a line of input from `stdin` and puts it into the array `line`. If `fgets` encounters an end-of-file before reading any characters, it will return NULL, and the program will exit.

Next, `sscanf` is called to parse the line and extract the numerator and denominator. `sscanf` will return 1 if it finds only the numerator. It will return 2 if it finds both the numerator and denominator. Note that the space before the slash in the format `"%d /%d"` is important. It tells `sscanf` to skip whitespace while looking for the slash.

The remainder of the program just echos the user input back to the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int numer, denom, count;
    char line[64];

    for (;;)
    {
        printf( "Enter decimal number: " );
        fflush( stdout );

        if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL ) {
            printf( "Bye\n" );
            break;
        }

        count = sscanf( line, "%d /%d", &numer, &denom );

        if ( count == 1 ) {
            denom = 1;
            printf( "You entered %d\n", numer );
        }
        else if ( count == 2 ) {
            printf( "You entered %d/%d\n", numer, denom );
        }
        else {
            printf( "You entered garbage\n" );
        }
    }
}
```